# How do I get my bouncing hamburger menu to stop bouncing after a certain amount of seconds have passed once the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am a noob at web dev and I am teaching myself using different online platforms (YouTube, Udemy, StackSkills, etc.).

Right now I am trying to focus on learning the basics of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/JQuery.

I created this hamburger menu for a custom site I am working on to help me learn and I wanted to try and get the bouncing hamburger menu to stop after a certain time threshold has passed.

I tried creating a class using JQuery that I could then use the CSS animation-duration property, but it stopped the bounce completely.

This is what I did using JQuery and CSS to try and get the effect I wanted that completely stopped the bounce animation effect rather than having it stopped after 5 seconds:

### **JQuery**

```
function bounceDuration() {
document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').classList.toggle('bounce-duration');
```

};

### **CSS**

```
.hamburger-menu.bounce-duration {
animation-duration: 5s;
```

}

Below you will find the current working code I have in its entirety (HTML, CSS, and JQuery). As you can see, the hamburger menu bounces indefinitely and I would like to somehow give it a timeout or duration of some sort. Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

```js
function sidebarToggle() {
    document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').classList.toggle('bounce-stop');
        document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("sidebar-toggle");
    });
}

sidebarToggle()
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
    z-index: 200;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

.hamburger-menu.bounce-stop {
    animation-name: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*
    Hamburger Menu Bounce
    ---------------------
    Description: - Up/Down animation
*/

.hamburger-menu {
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

.sidebar-toggle .hamburger-menu {
    right: 33rem;
    background-color: #555;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 100rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.sidebar {
    width: 40rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -40rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: right 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-toggle .sidebar {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
        <header class="header"></header>
        <section class="sidebar"></section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the iteration count to `2` (or any other number) rather than `infinite`:

```js
function sidebarToggle() {
    document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').classList.toggle('bounce-stop');
        document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("sidebar-toggle");
    });
}

sidebarToggle()
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
    z-index: 200;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

.hamburger-menu.bounce-stop {
    animation-name: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*
    Hamburger Menu Bounce
    ---------------------
    Description: - Up/Down animation
*/

.hamburger-menu {
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s 2 alternate;
    -o-animation: bounce 1s 2 alternate;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s 2 alternate;
    animation: bounce 1s 2 alternate;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

.sidebar-toggle .hamburger-menu {
    right: 33rem;
    background-color: #555;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 100rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.sidebar {
    width: 40rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -40rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: right 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-toggle .sidebar {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
        <header class="header"></header>
        <section class="sidebar"></section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just set some digit instead of `infinity` in `animation`

```
.hamburger-menu {
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s 5 alternate;
    -o-animation: bounce 1s 5 alternate;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s 5 alternate;
    animation: bounce 1s 5 alternate;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

it is [animation-iteration-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)

Comment: That's what that's for?  Wow, I'm such a noob at this. GREAT! Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.